# No response while running create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, freeze, no-response

[image: command prompt picture]

Above picture is a screenshot of what is happening while running "create-react-app"

I also tried

1. updating npm
2. using npx

**I tried most of the things still it doesn't work**

It worked once but now it is not working

Comment: There is no error in screenshot

Comment: it doesn't give any error it hangs after this and the command doesn't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I removed node 64 bit version and reinstalled 32 bit version and it worked. Alternatively you can try `npm cache clean` and retry generating app